# list of dependants objects dropped using drop table tablename cascade

Tags: java, postgresql

I need to get list of dependents objects dropped by below query 
drop table tablename cascade.

I need the objects dropped by cascade command in postgres.

Thanks,
Aru

Comment: Did you accidentally run a delete command or something?

Comment: The dependent objects that are dropped will be reported as a "notice" to the SQL client you are using: https://i.imgur.c,om/Fax84NM.png

Comment: I need to save the results of cascade drop command for logging